# DHTML: Gmail quota counter script?

Tags: javascript, ajax, dhtml

I am looking for a DHTML (preferably AJAX) that sorta gives the same effect as the quota counter on Gmail's start page. If I provide an initial value, I would like it to count upwards in a believeable fashion, i.e. it should always increase on revisit. This update should be dynamically as the user watches the counter.

Any ideas on how to approach this?

EDIT: I am not counting MB here, rather, number of documents in a set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google's counter is mainly for show and I would expect yours is as well. There's isn't some script running in the background that increases the quote for every user each second.

That being said, you can define a default value on page load and an interval for incrementing that timer and then you can do something like: http://jsfiddle.net/PD7wC/1/

Edit:
If you actually keep a count on the server side of the number of documents you have and want this real number to be reflected then you can edit the JS I provided to do an AJAX request every `1000ms`, for example, to get the new value.

If you want to get fancier you can create a new interval each time you're doing a request that animates a count up from the old value to the new. If for instance in the last second 10 new documents were added and you don't wanna just jump from `100` to `110` you can set an interval to increment by 1 every `1000ms / (110 - 100) = 100ms`

Comment: Thanks for the code! I just need to figure out how to make sure that the counter keeps incrementing on page reload and is not reset to the default.

Comment: You can accomplish this one of two ways:  

1. If you're keeping track of the document count on your server then just use that value on page load.  
2. If you're "faking" the document count then you can store the value in a cookie and retrieve the value on page load.

Comment: I am not doing (1) so I will go with 2. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what specifically you'd call for javascript/ajax, but if you access to server time you should be able to use some form of algorithm with that.

If not, then you'll probably have to look at storing the data in some form of storage on one end or the other and just count up over time/loops, but this seems intensive for the effect.